# New hidden service want exposure

Tags: onion-services, directory

I just started a new hidden service on tor and I just wanted to ask what's the best way to ensure that people know it exists???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are the same as for a clearnet site, advertising.

Use (anonymous) social media accounts to advertise the site. If you want to stay anonymous, make sure there is nothing in the social media profile that could lead to your identity (use a new email created over Tor).

Tell people that might be interested in your site about it. Again, if you want to stay anonymous, you must be anonymous to them.

Advertise on other hidden services. If other hidden services have a link to your site, it will be indexed by hidden service search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Just, try to connect using your Tor browser bundle. If you configured your hidden service right, you should see you server up and running.
If not, then you should check if you torrc is correct. Here is how you do it:

1. Type `tor --verify-config` or in Windows `tor --verify-config | more`
   to check your settings.
2. Check for output for this line: `Configuration was valid`.
3. If there is no such line, you should check your torrc file.

Also [this](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html) webpage might help you.

Comment: So what does that do that ensures people finding out about it???